TS unable to locate module when entry is in a higher-level directory than module's package.json
I'm setting up a TS monorepo, the structure looks like this:
/apps
  /web
/libs
  /hello
/dist

What I'm trying to accomplish is have all of the libraries build their output to the root-level dist directory.
I'm using pnpm workspaces, and when I add a library as a dependency on one of the apps, it creates a symlink in node_modules pointing to the library's directory:
/apps
  /web
    /node_modules
      /@thess
        /hello --> '../../../../libs/hello'

I have a sample library hello that just exports a function that outputs 'hello, world'. I am importing that in my web app via:
import { hello } from '@thess/hello';

This works fine IF:

I set the outDir in hello's tsconfig.json to ./dist
I set the main in hello's package.json to dist/index.js

In this case, the build output is contained in a subdirectory within the hello library's root, and everything works as expected.
This breaks IF:

I set the outDir in hello's tsconfig.json to ../../dist/libs/hello
I set the main in hello's package.json to ../../dist/libs/hello/index.js

Then tsc will not be able to locate the hello module on the import statement. I verified the build output is there and everything looks correct. Is there something that prevents the module importer from walking upwards in the directory tree from a module's root?

"What I'm trying to accomplish is have all of the libraries build their output to the root-level dist directory.". Why? This is highly unusual as the package is now pretty much invalid since the installed package cant magically bring in things on the outside along with it ,and so your relative paths to parent dirs would break when the module is installed since that changes the directory tree depth compared to the src . Not to mention, if it was ever published for use in other projects, it'd be unusable. Basiaclly this breaks basic expectations of how packages are packaged.

The only way you could do this would be to also copy the package.json over into the root level dist and modify its entry point paths to be relative. But this would be an odd and surprising thing to do, need to know about what your use case is. If looking to abstract away the built files from the source tree completely in a manageable way, you need something like Bazel (which is a big commitment). Usually you just ignore dist recursively from version control.

@adsy These are not going to be published, they are only used by other projects within the monorepo. Having all of the build output in a centralized place makes containerized development easier as I can volume mount a single directory instead of having to maintain mounts in every project for every dependency. Things like path aliases are also easier because I can create e.g. a 'libs' alias pointing to a central directory instead of aliasing every individual library.

Ok. I've been in this exact place before -- containerising workspaces. You are lucky to be using PNPM which can deal with this, its a mare with some other package managers. Typically the way to do this is like so https://pnpm.io/docker. Especially have a look at pnpm deploy which I think is the way you are going. This ensures relevant deps live in node_modules and so no expectations about package behaviors change, whilst at the same time reorientating the base directory to a package of your choice.

This also lets you utilise common docker layers for multiple package containers if you want. By running pnpm deploy for each app in the dockerfile, then copying out the relevant stuff for each app to its own image, you effectively create a common "lib" in the form of a docker layer with node_modules in, as managed by pnpm which gives you some nice guarantees about running same deps across app containers if that's what you want. And all whilst not breaking any expectation of any module loaders.
